# How to create sub resource with @RestRepositoryResource

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We are working on a Spring Boot API.
We use `@RestRepositoryResource` annotation to generate endpoints.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "datarow", path = "datarow")
public interface DataRowRepository extends MongoRepository<DataRow, String>
}
```

In the previous example, we create a endpoint `/api/datarow`.
But we want to change resource path like this : `/api/dataset/{id}/datarow`. Is it possible with `@RestRepositoryResource` ?

See our model :

```
public class Datarow {
    @Getter @Setter
    private String id;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String datasetId;
    @Getter @Setter
    private Address address;
}

public class Dataset {
    @Getter @Setter
    private String id;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String name;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String filePath;
    @Getter @Setter
    private Date uploadDate;
}
```

See our repository :

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "datarow", path = "datarow")
public interface DatarowRepository extends MongoRepository<Datarow, String> {
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: I guess you would want to GET only datarows belonging to dataset with ID, correct?

Comment: Yes. But we want to write datarow as a subresource of dataset. Not like that : `/api/datarow?datasetId=1` !.

Comment: Can you show entities for datarow and dataset?

Comment: I update with Datarow and Dataset model and an example of Datarow repository. Note the we use Mongo and not SQL.

Comment: I suspect you can create JPA like relationships for mongo entities as well. With that Spring Data REST would export such endpoint automatically

Comment: I started a bounty for your question (I'm also interested in a solution). Still, let me provide a partial answer. I had the same need in the past and the closest thing to a solution I had was to create a Controller (with nested RequestMapping) and forward to RestRepositoryResource's url. It works for "get" requests.

Comment: Moreover, when I looked around for this (a while ago), I remember reading something along the lines: "If an object is worthy of having its own Repository, then it may not be a true nested object. A object exposed through a repository means it can be written on its own. A true nested object would only be written through its parent, and thus wouldn't have its own repository."

Comment: Thanks Alex. We find this : We can nest resource using JPA data repository with Spring  Data Rest but the problem in our case is the bad integration of Mongo repository with Spring Data Rest. With Mongo repository it seems impossible to have nested resources in Spring Data Rest path. In our case, Mongo is a requirement, so we decided to don't use Spring Data Rest.